# Detecting swipe and automatically switching using the ViewPager

Tags: android

I want to create a viewpager at the top of my layout to allow users to swipe through a gallery images. When the page switches I want to change the text below that reflects the specific images. Is there a method I that listens for this action?

Also, I would like this slider to automatically switch every 5 seconds. Is there a method that switches?

Answer (score 4):

In order to detect when a ViewPager has changed views you need to implment ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener and set it on the ViewPager:

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new MyOnPageChangeListener);
```

which should have this:

```
// view pager item selected

public void onPageSelected(int i) {
    updateUI(i);
}
```

A full working example with an updating text view is on my site here: http://responsiveandroid.com/2012/01/26/android-viewpager-and-gallery-integration.html

To automatically page you need to use the Handler class

(untested)

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPagerCurrentItem++);
        }
    },5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection) and [Gestures](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html) for swipe detection.

And you can use timer for automatic switching. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)